# Python coroutine can one `send` without first doing `next`?

Tags: python, generator, coroutine, yield

When sending a value to a generator/coroutine, is there a way to avoid that initial `next(g)`?

```
def gen(n):
    m = (yield) or "did not send m to gen"
    print(n, m)

g = gen(10)
next(g)
g.send("sent m to g") # prints "10 sent m to g"
```

Without `next(g)`, we get

```
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator
```

Comment: Well... clearly there's no way if you get that type error.

Comment: Why is having to call `next` a problem to be solved?

Comment: @ScottHunter wanted to see if I could simplify my code as I ran into a case where I had to do this (this being "create a generator, next it, then send something to it") several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stems from [this bit of code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/genobject.c#L159-L171) in CPython's `gen_send_ex2`, i.e. it occurs if `gi_frame_state` is `FRAME_CREATED`.

The only place that matters for this discussion that sets `gi_frame_state` is [here in `gen_send_ex2`, after a (possibly None) value has been sent and a frame is about to be evaluated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aaeea78b0f8f4c8dfab5cd4eb6fb4c5fe1ee21e2/Objects/genobject.c#L218-L219).

Based on that, I'd say no, there's no way to send a non-None value to a just-started generator.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful in your specific case, but you could use a decorator to initialize coroutines.

```
def initialized(coro_func):
    def coro_init(*args, **kwargs):
        g = coro_func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(g)
        return g
    return coro_init


@initialized
def gen(n):
    m = (yield) or "did not send m to gen"
    print(n, m)


g = gen(10)
g.send("sent m to g") # prints "10 sent m to g"
```